# Star-shaped graph in dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Ḧi,

I'd like to draw a graph using the dot language that looks like a star ( a central node, wih all the other nodes with one link to this other node).

I've been googling around without finding much. Do you have a basic example ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`twopi`](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/twopi/twopi2.html) as the layouter and select radial layout.

Comment: just to be sure, radial is by default when you use twopi ? right ?

Comment: I'm not sure; I think so but if it isn't, just select the option.

Comment: the prpblem is that if i've too many elements at the second, there will be an overlap. I would like something like http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/softmaint.html

Comment: Just download the file (click on the image to see the source) and run it through the graphviz commands. The image was created with dot using `digraph` as the graph type.

Comment: I had to fight with the dot file, but I'm now satisfied by the rendering. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use this example

```
    graph g {

    node1 [label="1"]
    node2 [label="2"]
    node3 [label="3"]
    node4 [label="4"]
    node5 [label="5"]
    node6 [label="6"]
    node7 [label="7"]

   node4 -- node3
   node4 -- node2 
   node4 -- node1
   node4 -- node5
   node4 -- node7
   node4 -- node6

   }
```

Then invoke this commmand:
        neato -T svg -o direct.svg direct.dot

output as shown:

[image: image description]